# File in /etc/sudoers.d file not being read by sudo

Tags: linux, filenames, sudoers

I want to add a user in the sudoers file and I don't want to touch the original `/etc/sudoers` file, so I added a new file under directory `/etc/sudoers.d`.

The interesting thing is about the name of the newly added file. Initially, I named the file as `sudoers.local`, the file never got effective; then I renamed the file as `customize`, it got effective immediate. The file name `sudoers.customize` doesn't work either. It seems any file name containing `sudoers` doesn't work. Someone know the reason? In all three cases, the file has the proper permission `-r--r-----`.

The OS is 64 bits CentOS 6.5.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From the [sudoers man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html):

> The #includedir directive can be used to create a sudo.d directory that the system package manager can drop sudoers rules into as part of package installation. For example, given:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

> sudo will read each file in /etc/sudoers.d, ***skipping file names that end in ‘~' or contain a ‘.' character*** to avoid causing problems with package manager or editor temporary/backup files.

Comment: I had used `file.conf` and never realized that was causing the problem. Thanks so much!